# Does virtual DOM's diffing algorithm pin-point the only difference and patch real DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, diff, virtual

What I learned about Virtual DOM and its diff algorithm is, that when a change occurs in certain component(or element / and its children as well), it is efficient to reconciliate that particular component and children because other than that, other DOM component will not be changed.

However what I already know is that the time-consuming part of DOM manipulation is the moment of recalculating element's style(like CSS).

If a component in between of many other components changes, such as height style changes or get unmounted, by means of such change, **sibling components below** will be affected, in which the style of those components should be all re-rendered(relayout or repaint).

Then, doesn't this mean that the object of React - manipulating only the changed part of view by virtual DOM and diff algorithm - would not be achieved?

Am I misunderstanding, or is this normal?

If this is normal(situation that due to the changed component in the middle of other components, other components below also have to be modified), then what is the advantage of React compared to plain DOM manipulating method, other than batch process or declarative method? Is this okay to call it "patch"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React 'virtual DOM' is just a javascript object. It is nothing to do with styles and layouts at the time of the reconciliation. After each render React can diff this object with the result of the previous render and only updates the changed attribute of the corresponding DOM element.
Here is an explanatory image from React doc, you can see that the update is well localized.

[image]

Comment: I get the point of your answer, thank you. But what if style or layout changes after state changes? By events, change of CSS property or unmount of element might happen, I think.
If change of attribute does not affect the layout or painting, that is okay. But what if it affects them?

Comment: Most of the case there is no Css, unomount and layout changes outside of react. If there is an event in a React application it is rendered in React. But anyway if some layout is changing due of resize for example it does not affect the Dom and it handled by the browser. React is responsible only for the Dom manipulation.

Comment: I get it. DOM is not related with CSS stuffs, and CSS is rather matter to be handled by browser. Thank you for your explanation. So DOM manipulations that gets advantage of React or any other enhanced frameworks and libraries are not so related to CSS related stuff.

Comment: Yes, the frameworks can only manipulates the styles/css throught the dom directly or indirectly. And from this the browsers is responsible for the rest of the rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Your concern is that changing the style of a parent component might trigger browser layout of its child components

However, this problem still occurs regardless of whether you are using react's virtual dom or not

- The benefit in react's virtual dom, is that it aggregates dom operations and debounces (de-dupes) the redundant operations

  This broad optimization usually results in fewer total dom operations than if you "hand-coded" it
- In rare circumstances, you might be able to produce a more optimal result without react's virtual dom, by very carefully managing dom operations manually

  Going 'manual' is rarely worth the consideration

Comment: What I pointed was the **sibling** components, not children components of the changed component. But anyway, I got the point what you said. So you mean that by virtual DOM usually we can get fewer DOM manipulations, and batch the DOM operations we need to do(which are optimizations).

Comment: Ah, I see I had misread.. Yes, you have the right idea, that the virtual dom is a way to broadly optimize dom operations, however it is not guaranteed to be more efficient, it just usually is during rapid development